# Removing a cell from the tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview added to a viewController (I wanted it this way).
Each cell of the tableview has a segmentcontroller, when the user clicks on it the cell deletes/removes.

I end up getting an exception, and i have no clue how to solve it.

> 2012-01-23 15:35:26.729 TestProject [21003:707] *** Assertion failure
>   in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
>
> 2012-01-23 15:35:26.761 TestProject [21003:707] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

My code so far;

**in the button event;**

```
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)segmentController.superview.superview;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        Person *person= [[self allThdata] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                [self.allThdata removeObjectIdenticalTo:person];

        [self.myTableView beginUpdates];

        [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

        [self.myTableView endUpdates];
```

I have also tried `removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row` and `removeObject: person` . None of this worked

Answer (score 1):

Call to `removeObjectAtIndex:` should be inside `beginUpdates` block.

This should do the trick:

```
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)segmentController.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
[self.myTableView beginUpdates];
[[self allThdata] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
[self.myTableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I think i tried this, but `[[self allThdata] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` line was above `[self.myTableView beginUpdates];`.

Comment: it should be below `[self.myTableView beginUpdates];`.